# Which packages are auto-removable in apt/synaptic

Tags: ubuntu, debian, synaptic-pkg-mgr

What is the definition of "auto removable" and other sections ("manual"?) in Synaptic?

Intuitively it should be the list of packages that are not required by other packages but this does not seem to be the case. Same with "manual" and "local" - it looks like those are assigned randomly. :(

Is there some official documentation that I have failed to find?

Comment: Packages that have been *automatically installed as dependencies* and not required anymore.

Comment: Is there a way to get similar list but with suggestions treated as requirements ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Auto-removable are packages that can be automatically removed once the software that depends on them is no longer installed.

The full list is printed with:

```
$ apt-mark showauto
```

### Example

You install the package `scid` in hope it will help improve your chess skills:

```
$ sudo apt-get install scid
...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  fonts-lmodern libpotrace0 libptexenc1 libsnack-alsa libsynctex1 libtcl8.5 libtk-img libtk8.5 libzzip-0-13 lmodern scid-data tcl-snack tcl8.5 tcllib tdom tex-common texlive-base texlive-binaries texlive-games texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-base-doc tk8.5
Suggested packages:
  libtk-img-doc toga2 phalanx glaurung crafty scid-spell-data scid-rating-data tcl-snack-doc tcl-tclreadline perl-tk
Recommended packages:
  libsnack2
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fonts-lmodern libpotrace0 libptexenc1 libsnack-alsa libsynctex1 libtcl8.5 libtk-img libtk8.5 libzzip-0-13 lmodern scid scid-data tcl-snack tcl8.5 tcllib tdom tex-common texlive-base texlive-binaries texlive-games texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-base-doc tk8.5
0 upgraded, 23 newly installed, 0 to remove and 211 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/94.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 227 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
```

You later find scid really awkward to use compared to pychess, so you uninstall it:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge scid
...
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  scid*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 211 not upgraded.
After this operation, 6,695 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
```

However, look at those maths: 227 MB of additional space will be used; 6,695 kB disk space will be freed. Huh?

You might want to get rid all of those dependency libraries scid depended on but are now no longer required:

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
...
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libsnack-alsa libtcl8.5 libtk-img libtk8.5 scid-data tcl-snack tcl8.5 tcllib tdom texlive-games tk8.5
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 11 to remove and 211 not upgraded.
After this operation, 40.5 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
```

**So what happened with the rest 180 MB? I have no idea.** But here they are.

```
$ sudo apt-get purge fonts-lmodern libpotrace0 libptexenc1 libsynctex1 libtcl8.5 libtk8.5 libzzip-0-13 lmodern tcl8.5 tex-common texlive-base texlive-binaries texlive-games texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-base-doc tk8.5
...
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  fonts-lmodern* libpotrace0* libptexenc1* libsynctex1* libtcl8.5* libtk8.5* libzzip-0-13* lmodern* tcl8.5* tex-common* texlive-base* texlive-binaries* texlive-games* texlive-latex-base*
  texlive-latex-base-doc* tk8.5*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 16 to remove and 211 not upgraded.
After this operation, 180 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

To have `apt` treat suggested packages as required, add

```
APT::Install-Suggests "true";
```

to one of the files in */etc/apt/apt.conf.d/*.

Comment: And what's the difference between `automatic` and `auto removable`, both of which can show up?

Comment: @NielsBom _Automatic_ are packages that are auto-installed as dependencies. _Auto-removable_ are automatic packages which no longer serve as dependencies (dependents no longer installed) and can thus be removed.